# 'wordcloud' is not defined python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a wordcloud on movie genre in this link but I have some error,  `name 'wordcloud' is not defined` even if the package
`wordcloud` is installed.

Could anybody help me please, the version of python is 3.6.3.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from wordcloud import WordCloud 

# explorer les pandas series 
movies=pd.read_csv ('bit.ly/imdbratings') 

data=movies.genre.value_counts()
print(data)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
wordcloud=wordcloud(background_color='white',mode="RGB", width=2000 , height=1000).generate(data)
plt.title("test")
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to look how did you import, and what did you import, look this line:

```
wordcloud=wordcloud(background_color='white',mode="RGB", width=2000 , height=1000).generate(data)
```

should be capitalized to

```
wordcloud=Wordcloud(background_color='white',mode="RGB", width=2000 , height=1000).generate(data)
```

because you imported :

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply , it works well but now i have an error like this . expected string or bytes-like object.

Comment: @Ilyas FANTASTIC!!! It looks like the problem of the Original Question was solved, to be clean, the best way to continue is ask a new question, so further readers won't be confuse :)! Don't forget to vote and accept if it was helpuf, and share to me the link to the new question if you want

Comment: @Damien i could only post a question after 90 min so have you any idea about this error please

Comment: @Ilyas I could give to you hints, because I don't see the full stack error, it look like you give bad arguments to the constructor, how many arguments and wich type are they? do you have the full error?

Comment: i want just a basic wordcloud based on movies genre , this is the full error 
 
    
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 546, in generate_from_text
    words = self.process_text(text)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 513, in process_text
    words = re.findall(regexp, text, flags)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xd973cf8>